# Fill the values with each column combination with some default values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
df
col1    col2    col3
1907    CD       49
1907    FR       33
1907    SA       34
1908    PR        1
1908    SA       37
1909    PR       16
1909    SA       38
```

Now CD is not present with col1 1908 and 1909 values, FR not present with 1908 and 1909 values and PR not present wth 1907.

Now I want to create rows with col2 values which are not with all col1 values with col3 values as 0.

So final dataframe will look like,

```
df
col1    col2    col3
1907    CD       49
1907    FR       33
1907    SA       34
1907    PR        0
1908    CD        0
1908    FR        0
1908    PR        1
1908    SA       37
1908    CD        0
1908    FR        0
1909    PR       16
1909    SA       38
```

I could do this using a for loop with every possible col2 values and comparing with every col1 group. But I am looking for shortcuts to do it most efficiently.

Comment: are you sure your result is correct? last 4 rows should be 1909 i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for all combinations filled by `0`:

```
df = df.set_index(['col1','col2']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
print (df)
    col1 col2  col3
0   1907   CD    49
1   1907   FR    33
2   1907   PR     0
3   1907   SA    34
4   1908   CD     0
5   1908   FR     0
6   1908   PR     1
7   1908   SA    37
8   1909   CD     0
9   1909   FR     0
10  1909   PR    16
11  1909   SA    38
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['col1'].unique(), 
                                  df['col2'].unique()], names=['col1','col2'])
df = df.set_index(['col1','col2']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.pivot(*df).stack(dropna = False).fillna(0).rename('col3').reset_index()
```

or [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

```
df.pivot_table(*df.iloc[:,::-1],fill_value = 0).unstack().rename('col3').reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    col1 col2  col3
0   1907   CD  49.0
1   1907   FR  33.0
2   1907   PR   0.0
3   1907   SA  34.0
4   1908   CD   0.0
5   1908   FR   0.0
6   1908   PR   1.0
7   1908   SA  37.0
8   1909   CD   0.0
9   1909   FR   0.0
10  1909   PR  16.0
11  1909   SA  38.0
```